# I'm making a bot to test my skills with python, I'm trying to make it search youtube

Tags: python, youtube, bots, discord.py

I'm making a bot for discord, so far it works, i have it searching youtube and it displaying a result, but only the first one, I'd like it to show a list that you can select from to show.

This is the code I have that works

```
async def yt(ctx, self, *, search):
    
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(\S{11})',
                                htm_content.read().decode())
    await ctx.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

I am fairly new and I can't find a good example to how to do it.

Comment: did you try to use `search_results[1]`, `search_results[2]`, etc. or simply  use `for`-loop `for item in search_results: ....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Embed()` to display list with options to select and use `add_reaction()` to add buttons with `emoji` which you can click. Next you need `wait_for('reaction_add',...)` to wait for clicked button. Next you can remove message with options and send message with selected item.

```
import os
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(aliases=['yt'])
async def youtube(ctx):
    
    # search results
    options = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH']
    
    # convert list to dictionary with emoji as key
    codepoint_start = 127462  # Emoji `A`
    options = {chr(i): f"{chr(i)} - {v}" for i, v in enumerate(options, start=codepoint_start)}

    # create list to display
    embed = Embed(title='Select', description="\n".join(options.values()))
    
    # display it as message
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    # add reactions to get selection    
    for reaction in options:
        await message.add_reaction(reaction)

    # function which check if selection is correct
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user != message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in list(options)

    # wait for selection
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        
    # remove message with options
    await message.delete()
    
    # send selection    
    selected = options[reaction.emoji]
    selected = selected.split(' - ', 1)[-1] # remove emoji 
    #print('selected:', selected)
    await ctx.send(selected)
    
# --- main ---

print('start bot')
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
bot.run(TOKEN)  # `bot`, not `client`
print('stop bot')
```

[image]

Comment: used the code, works beautifully, thanks man